# eslint rule to required imported objects to have the same name as file?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I seem to remember there was a rule for this but I can't find it. Basically something to require that imported objects have the same name as the package.

For example, this would be considered incorrect:

```
import MyButton from './ui/Button.js'; // NOT OK
```

because the package is called "Button", not "MyButton".

This would be fine:

```
import Button from './ui/Button.js'; // OK
```

Maybe even this:

```
import UserList from './ui/user-list.js'; // OK
```

Any idea if a rule can be used for this?

Comment: Is this the rule you are looking for? https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few proposals out there for this rule idea:

- https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1041
- https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/325

But none of them have made it into an `eslint` release yet.

Answer (score 1):

The rule your looking for is `filenames/match-exported`.

https://github.com/selaux/eslint-plugin-filenames#matching-exported-values-match-exported

Comment: package is not actively maintained :(